# Multiple 3D plots in one window

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to plot multiple plots in one window (graphics are displayed qt)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sure.

The keyword is **subplot**. Read [this](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#figures-subplots-axes-and-ticks) for a basic overview.

Just look at this official example [from here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/subplot3d_demo.html):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# imports specific to the plots in this example
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import get_test_data

# Twice as wide as it is tall.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.5))

#---- First subplot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
Z = np.sin(R)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                       linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
ax.set_zlim3d(-1.01, 1.01)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=10)

#---- Second subplot
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)

plt.show()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: That's what I'm searching for. Thank you very much.