# Getting an array of 3D subplots from matlab?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to generate a panel of 3D subplots using matplotlib. All of the example code I can find online have to run a separate line of code to instantiate each 3D subplot. For example,

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax11 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection='3d')
ax12 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2, projection = '3d').
```

Is there a way to get an array of axes, such as when we call

```
fig1,ax1 = plt.subplots(3,3)
```

?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/subplot3d.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Multiple 3D plots in one window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616547/python-multiple-3d-plots-in-one-window)